# Type struct Mycontract.User memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Mycontract.User storage pointer

Tags: solidity, storage, struct, memory

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;
contract Mycontract{
    uint256 a;
    struct User
    {  string name; }
    User[] users;
    function foo() public{
      **User storage user=User("hey");**  
     users.push(user);
    }
    function get() public view returns(string memory)
    {   return users[0].name; }
}
```

However when the above highlighted statement changed to the below statement will solve the error:

```
 User memory user=User("hey");
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind this changing from memory to storage?

Comment: Yeah, `storage` is for pointing to global (state) variables, and `memory` is for allocating local variables. In both cases, it applies only to structs and arrays.

Comment: Understood thanks,so if we referring storage in a statement then always  it should consist of state variables?

Answer (score 2):

Variable in contract by default are of `storage`, i.e. they are state variables.
And new struct default allocation within function is `memory`.

Hence the compiler warning.